# Making a textbox hang outside of WPF application c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am interested in having a textbox that will extend outside of the window I am using for my application. I am hoping that the text box will extend 1 inch out of the right side of my application without having to extend the whole application by an inch. I have tried creating a pop up and placing it in the needed area however some times the pop up moves or goes under my application. I am looking for a solution that is not a popup. Any ideas?

Comment: It does not look like a good idea: what if app is running in a Windows.Maximized mode? Regards,

Comment: Thanks guys, The app is "always on top" and takes up 110px of my screen ALWAYS. there is an option to make it 35px and i want to be able to hover over the textbox and for it to grow to 110px again.. So its a conditional change that i need but thanks for the concern alex